# Diagnosing directory deletions on Linux

Tags: linux

Yesterday evening I lost all of my project, or to be more exact, the directory tree named `f/` that was in my home directory.

I restored from a backup.

A few minutes ago it disappeared again (fortunately for me, I started backing up with every rebuild since then and I rebuild often so no losses this time). I'm not aware of any executable I could have run or written myself that could've done this.

Since the issue seems to be isolated to `~/f/`, I think it's some buggy script that wanted to do `rm -rf` and instead did `rm -r f`.

How can I find the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* `rm` is indeed involved and it's `/bin/rm`:

1. `sudo ln /bin/rm /bin/rm-real`
2. Create a log directory writable to anyone:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/rm-logdir
   chmod a+w /tmp/rm-logdir
   ```
3. Write a wrapper script (named `script`) like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   pstree -spa "$$" >> "/tmp/rm-logdir/$$"
   exec /bin/rm-real "$@"
   ```
4. Adjust ownership and permissions of the script so it can mimic `rm` (non-POSIX fast way:`chmod --reference=/bin/rm script; sudo chown --reference=/bin/rm script`).
5. Replace `/bin/rm` with the script:

   ```
   sudo mv script /bin/rm
   ```

   From now on anything that calls `/bin/rm` will be logged to a file in `/tmp/rm-logdir`.
6. Wait for the problem to occur again.
7. Examine files in `/tmp/rm-logdir`. One of them will hopefully contain something like this:

   ```
   systemd,1
     `-tmux: server,2652
         `-bash,8605
             `-rm,15100 /bin/rm -r f
                 `-pstree,15101 -spa 15100
   ```

   with command line arguments and PIDs; note the last but one line. The above is in fact an example from my tests in Kubuntu, where I run `rm -r f` in interactive `bash`. Another example (not triggered directly by me) was:

   ```
   systemd,1
     `-kdeinit5,1679
         `-ksmserver,1700
             `-rm,16400 /bin/rm /home/kamil/.config/session/kate_10d8d5de64000154299531000000017000020_1542995310_707537
                 `-pstree,16401 -spa 16400
   ```

   It proves other tools (`ksmserver` in this case) use the wrapper script.

Notes:

- `pstree` is not required by POSIX, it may be unavailable. You can use `ps`, you can read information directly from `/proc`.
- In multi-user environment the solution is not safe. Anyone can write to the log directory. This is deliberately set to capture anyone's `rm` invocations in a lazy, quick and dirty way. But then anyone can spoof the results.

To revert:

```
sudo mv /bin/rm-real /bin/rm
```

(note this will overwrite the script, so if there's no other copy of it, the script itself will be lost).